How to run an entire azure pipeline, start to finish, inside a Docker container?
Is there a way to define the container where your entire pipeline stages and jobs can run, from start to finish, without stopping the container in-between the stages.
I am creating a azure pipeline for building each  microservices (which includes stages for mvn deploy, docker build and release, ecr release, mvn release). The docker build needs the build artifacts that is generated by mvn deploy stage for building docker image. I tried using the containers in the pipeline that i have written inside microservice to trigger the pipeline for building microservices.
The container seems to initialize and working but it is getting stop after each stage .The builds that is generated in build stage is not there when the docker build and release stage is running.
in trigger pipeline:
  containers:
  - container: dockerContainer
    image: image name
    endpoint: dockerhubcreds
    options: --user 0:0

pipeline for building microservices:
  - stage: Build
    dependsOn: SetupMaven
    jobs:
    - job: Build_job
      displayName: Build
      container: dockerContainer

When I tried the above method, the container is stopping after each stage. Also i am using the ubuntu self hosted agent for testing and Microsoft hosted agent (ubuntu-latest) for production.


what aspect of the container stopping is impacting you?

@bryanbcook I have the stages (mvn deploy, docker build,release, ecr release, and mvn release). The docker build needs the build artifacts that is generated by mvn deploy stage for building docker image. In this case, the container is stopping after mvn deploy, so the build artifacts from mvn deploy are not accessible in docker build stage

ok, so the concern is that the files produced by the mvn tasks are not persisted between stages (which is the case regardless whether this is a container or a standard tasks). what are the file paths to the build artifacts generated by mvn?

The target/project-name.jar generated by mvn is used by the stage 'docker build'.
But now i grouped all the tasks in one job. now it is working.
When i tried the self hosted agent in docker container i was getting the - error ##[error]ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1.

if you're running your self-hosted agent as a docker image and trying to run docker inside it requires additional configuration for your build agent.

As mentioned by @Rui Jarimba, containers are used at a job level. If you are using a MS-hosted agent, each job gets a fresh agent, and the container will be brand new as well.
If you want all your stages/jobs run in the same container, you can set up a self-hosted agent in Docker and use this agent to run your pipeline. See Run a self-hosted agent in Docker for the detailed steps.
Note: When you start the image, ensure DON'T add --once in docker run. Otherwise, with the --once flag, you will get a fresh agent container for every pipeline job.

Thank you very much for the response. If i set up a self-hosted agent in Docker container, does everyone who needs to run the pipeline also setup the self-hosted agent?

No. Once you have set up a self-hosted agent, you can see it in the agent pool. Any one having permissions to the agent pool can use it in the pipeline. See Set agent pool security in Azure Pipelines for the detailed permissions.

You cannot use the same container instance in all jobs in a pipeline. Keep in mind that each job might be picked up by multiple build agents, which might be running in different machines.
Containers are used at a job level, not a stage. Containers can be used to run a list of tasks within a job, not a stage. If you need fine-grained control at the individual step level, step targets allow you to choose container or host for each step.
See Define container jobs for more details.

I think it's important to recognize that this limitation isn't just for containers. Jobs are scoped to an agent, and depending on your setup you would have a different agent for each job.

@bryanbcook yes that's correct.

As a core concept, pipelines do not execute end-to-end as a single process. A pipeline can execute multiple jobs in sequence or simultaneously across a variety of operating systems. Jobs are scoped to agents, and each job can potentially use a different agent. If you split your process up into different stages or jobs, you cannot make assumptions about file system outputs from previous jobs.
If you have a multi-stage pipeline and you want to make assumptions about the file system, you need to guarantee the state of the file system for that job. This is accomplished by creating pipeline artifacts that can be carried forward from one stage to another.
The download task downloads artifacts to the $(Pipeline.Workspace)/<artifact-name> folder. Ideally, you would mount this folder into your container, but the folder would need to exist prior. Because the container mounts the workspace already, you can copy the artifact to the desired assumed location.
For example, if you wanted to use maven to produce a build artifact that is deployed later in a different stage. This process is the same if you are using containers.

stages:
- stage: build
  jobs:
  - job: build
    steps:
    # steps to build artifact located in /target/project-name.jar
    - ...

    # publish /target folder as artifact to be available for next stage
    - publish: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/target
      artifact: build
      displayName: 'Publish Build Artifact'

- stage: deploy
  jobs:
  - job: deploy
    steps:
    # download build artifact
    - download: current
      artifact: build
      displayName: 'Download Build Artifact'

    - task: CopyFiles@2 # move artifact into the original folder
      inputs:
        sourceFolder: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/build
        taregetFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/target

    # steps to work with the artifact like it was already there
    - ...

